# Distance between tangency points in a circumscribed isosceles trapezoid

Tags: geometry

"A circle of radius $5$ is inscribed in an isosceles trapezoid $ABCD$. If the major base measures $20$, what is the distance between the tangency points of the non-parallel sides?"

[image]

My first approach was defining a point $F \in CD$ such that $AF \perp DC$.

Then, for an isosceles trapezium to have an inscribed circle, it must satisfy that $AB+CD=AD+BC$

Define $AD=BC=y$ and $AB=x$

Then: $20+x=2y$.

$AF=10$

By Pythagoras' theorem: $DF^2+AF^2=AD^2$ = $(\frac {20-x}{2})^2+10^2=y^2$

Solving this equation system I got that $x=5, y=\frac{25}{2}$, but I don't see how to continue. I think that calculating $MN$ solves the problem but I don't know how.

Any hints? Are my approaches wrong?

Comment: "In a isosceles trapezoid ABCD is inscribed a circle of radius 5" is pretty non-standard English. You might consider rewriting it to "A circle of radius 5 is inscribed in an isosceles trapezoid ABCD" for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, english isn't my native language and i wrote it fast. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, just trying to help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically done. Since $AM = \frac12AB$ by external tangents, you know the ratio $\frac{AM}{AD}$, and $\frac{MD}{AD}$, so you can take a weighted average of $AB$ and $DC$ to get $MN$.

(If you prefer, you can draw $X$ the intersection of $AD$ and $BC$ and use the similar triangles $\triangle ABX$, $\triangle MNX$, $\triangle DCX$, which is an equivalent approach.)

Comment: Sorry, i understood everything except the $X$ point, i don't know where is the intersection of AD and BC. If it's not a nuisance, could you explain me?

Comment: Because $AD \parallel MN \parallel BC$, we know that wherever that point is (and we don't know anything special about it), it creates similar triangles. Using those triangles is another way to relate the ratio $AM : MD$ to the triple ratio $AB : MN : DC$.